# How can I do something like 'categoryname/seoname' in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm doing a project with Yii2. And I'm trying to do so with UrlManager. Like this;

```
'<CategoryID:\w+>/<SEO:\w+>'=>'soru/goster',
```

But Yii2 is showing "404 Not found". How do i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables in url rules in config;

```
'<category>/<seo>'=>'soru/goster'
```

Then in your controller (I changed the name as I you didn't post your controller.;

```
public function actionGoster($seo) //you can also access $category
{
  if (isset($seo))
  { 
  //do your lookup 
  }
}
```

Access the url like this;

```
http://yourDomain/index.php/CATEGORY/SEO/
```

I do this to look up items in the database which allows for SEO friendly urls;

```
'plants/<name>'=>'catalog/viewSingle'
```

Controller;

```
public function actionViewSingle($name)
{
   if (isset($name)) 
   {
      $model = Plant::model()->findByAttributes(array('url_name'=>$name));

      if ($model)
      { //do stuff }
      else
      {
      //do matches and find similar plants that has these characters...
      $this->render('error_matches', array('matches'=>$matches));
      }
   }
   else
   { 
      //404
   }
```

Edit:

To avoid all URLs going to this make sure you include default rules;

```
'<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: it does affect to "site/about,site/contact".Now, it doesn't work And breadcumb began to fail :S Error:"The "label" element is required for each link."

Comment: make sure that the default rules are present ('<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/') because they are required. Also try placing it above and below the defaults and testing it.